# How to save the downloaded file on "on my iphone" folder?

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-ios

to be short and clear i am trying to download a pdf file and save it "on my iphone" folder.

```
 Future<File?> createFile() async {
   String attachment = "attachments";
   Directory dir;
   File? attachmentPath;
   if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    if (await _requestPermission(Permission.storage)) {
    dir = (await getExternalStorageDirectory())!;
    attachmentPath =
        File('${dir.parent.path}/$attachment/${getFileName()}');

    }
   } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
  if (await _requestPermission(Permission.storage)) {
    dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory());
    attachmentPath =
        File('${dir.path}/$attachment/${getFileName()}');
  }
}
if (!await attachmentPath!.exists()) {
  await attachmentPath.create(recursive: true);
}
return attachmentPath;
}


Future<bool> _requestPermission(Permission permission) async {
print(await permission.isGranted);
if (await permission.isGranted) {
  return true;
} else {
  var result = await permission.request();
  if (result == PermissionStatus.granted) {
    return true;
 }
  }
 return false;
}
```

i have also enabled LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace and UIFileSharingEnabled in \ios\Runner\Info.plist and i can't find the app folder in "on my iphone"
`<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>`
`<true/>`
`<key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>`
`<true/>`

Answer (score 0):

iOS apps are *sandboxed*. Download into the sandbox (e.g. the Documents folder).

You have no direct access to the "On My iPhone" folder. Apple does (for example, Safari downloads are saved to that folder) but you do not. The *user* can be given the facility to move the downloaded PDF to "On My iPhone" (via the UIDocumentPickerViewController), but you cannot perform the move spontaneously yourself.